# How to install Struts 2 Wizard in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, wizard

How do I install Struts2 in eclipse to be seen in facets of the project when I create a new project 'Dynamic Web'?

As you can see, I already Struts1 on my computer, but it's not me who installed it, so I do not know how.

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/787278screen.png

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to change digits on the right side to 2.3.

Comment: It is facets not aspects.

Comment: 2.3 isn't available in the list, because struts 2 isn't installed yet...